# Generating columns names with pandas assign

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with ten columns and one mean column and I would like to do something like this:

```
monthly_volume:
Month 1984 1985 1986 Mean
1     10   5    4    6.33 
2     9    5    8    7.33
3     4    8    1    4.33
4     5    8    1    4.67
5     3    6    3    3.33
..    ..   ..   ..   ....

for year in range(1, 4):
   monthly_volume = monthly_volume.assign(difference = 
       monthly_volume[monthly_volume.columns[-year+1]] - monthly_volume['MEAN'])
```

However, I am not quite sure how to easily generate a new column name (for example difference_2) without doing it manually.

Thank you!

Comment: You could broadcast the calculation across the section of the frame, then collapse a multi-index or map to new column names. If you include a sample of the dataframe and expected output someone would be able to provide a specific answer.

Comment: You can use f-strings so `monthly_volume[f'difference_{year}'] = ...`

Comment: @HenryEcker I've provided snippet

Comment: @ALollz That's the issue! Assign don't take strings...

Comment: But there's not really any need for assign. Sure it's convenient if you want to chain a bunch of stuff, but you're simply creating a column so use the `df[col_name] = ` syntax

Comment: @ALollz Aaa I see! Sorry! I always thought that variables cannot be generated. Didn't think about it properly

Comment: Should I delete this post then?

Answer (score 1):

```
for year in range(1, 4):
   kwards = {'difference': monthly_volume[monthly_volume.columns[-year+1]] - monthly_volume['MEAN']}
   monthly_volume = monthly_volume.assign(**kwards)
```